# Multivariable Resultant

Tags: matrices, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, discriminant, resultant

I want to compute the resultant of $f_1,\cdots, f_m \in K[x_1,\cdots x_n]$ where $f_1, \cdots,f_m$ are forms of degrees $d_1,\cdots ,d_n$ respectively. Does anyone have any idea on how could I do this?

Comment: First of all, what is your definition of the multivariable resultant? Secondly, Google gives https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0007036 as the **first** result for multivariable resultant - have you attempted to skim this paper?

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much.

Comment: SageMath also has a generic multivariate resultant method built in http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/polynomial_rings/sage/rings/polynomial/multi_polynomial_element.html